# Verb of principal clause followed by relative caluse

Tags: word-order, relative-clauses, clauses

1. The boy **who ate fruit** came.
2. The boy came **who ate fruit**.
   Here both sentences have relative clause *"who ate fruit"* and a principal clause "the boy came". Here is my question: Both sentences convey same meaning right? If they're different what is the difference in meaning? And could we use verb of principal clause after a relative clause as in sentence 1 and word order of sentence 1 is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st example is correct.   The relative clause modifies the subject 'boy'.

The 2nd example is unusual.

Comment: The second one is very much marked as poetic or archaic, yeah. The structure can definitely be found in older Bible translations, for example, or in Milton's famous sonnet: "They also serve who stand and wait."